# Difficulty with Associations

Tags: cakephp, associations, models

I currently have a few models.  The associations are as follows:

- Schedule hasMany Match
- Event hasMany Schedule
- Event hasMany Division
- TeamEvent hasMany Match (two, away and home)
- Team hasMany TeamEvent (links actual teams to divisions)
- Division hasMany TeamEvent

I am trying to find all of the matches per TeamEvent.

```
$this->TeamEvent->find('all', array('conditions' => array('TeamEvent.team_id' => $this->Team->id)));
```

The problem is that all of the matches are being put into the TeamEvent with the id 1.

This is the relevant SQL:

```
SELECT `Match`.`id`, `Match`.`schedule_id`, `Match`.`event_id`, `Match`.`home_team_id`, `Match`.`away_team_id`, `Match`.`home_result`, `Match`.`away_result`, `Match`.`matchtime`, `Schedule`.`id`, `Schedule`.`week`, `Schedule`.`map_name`, `Schedule`.`start_date`, `Schedule`.`end_date`, `Schedule`.`event_id`, `HomeTeam`.`id`, `HomeTeam`.`division_id`, `HomeTeam`.`team_id`, `HomeTeam`.`active`, `HomeTeam`.`win`, `HomeTeam`.`loss`, `AwayTeam`.`id`, `AwayTeam`.`division_id`, `AwayTeam`.`team_id`, `AwayTeam`.`active`, `AwayTeam`.`win`, `AwayTeam`.`loss` FROM `openplay`.`matches` AS `Match` LEFT JOIN `openplay`.`schedules` AS `Schedule` ON (`Match`.`schedule_id` = `Schedule`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `openplay`.`team_events` AS `HomeTeam` ON (`Match`.`home_team_id` = `HomeTeam`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `openplay`.`team_events` AS `AwayTeam` ON (`Match`.`away_team_id` = `AwayTeam`.`id`) WHERE ((`HomeTeam`.`team_id` = 1) OR (`AwayTeam`.`team_id` = 1)) ORDER BY `Match`.`matchtime` desc LIMIT 1
```

As you can see, the only condition is the Away and Home TeamEvent.  How do I make it so that it also does checks Schedule?

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Team->id
```

This holds the current pointer to the Team model - I wouldn't recommend using this unless you know what you are doing, I would suggest using a parameter in your function call:

```
public function something($team_id) {
    $matches = $this->TeamEvent->find('all', array('conditions' => array('TeamEvent.team_id' => $team_id)));
//etc

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't work even when using the parameter.

Comment: If you update your original question with your controller code it might help